# Using dateTime function in a foreach loop to check is set date is greater than current date

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement, pdo

I am attempting to use the dateTime function against a date/time field I have in my database to check against each other as to whether it is greater than or less than each other.

The issue I am running into is that if I set the condition to `if ($date >= $end_date)`, then I only get the `$noEvents` to output, even though there are `end_date` fields that are actually greater than the `$date` (current dateTime). Then the same happens if I change the condition to `if ($date <= $end_date)`, except vise versa.

It seems as if this if statement is only reading once and not looping through each record.

Here is what is in my database. The first two records have dates greater than today. The third record has a day less than or previous of today.

If the condition is : `if ($date >= $end_date)`

I only get `$noEvents`.

If the condition is: `if ($date <= $end_date)`

I get all of the three database records displaying, even though the record titled "Test" should not be displaying.

Does anyone know why this isn't working correctly?

[image]

```
if ($date <= $end_date) {
                $noEvents = 'No events are scheduled yet.';
            } else {

events  CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_name` text NOT NULL,
  `display_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `event_img` text NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 


try {   
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname=name', $username, $password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql_events = "
        SELECT *
        FROM events
        ORDER BY end_date ASC
        LIMIT 3
    ";
    if ($event_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_events)) {
        $event_stmt->execute();
        $event_rows = $event_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($event_rows as $event_row) {
            $event_name = $event_row['event_name'];
            $display_date = $event_row['display_date'];
            $event_description = $event_row['description'];
            $end_date = $event_row['end_date'];
            $date = new DateTime("now");
            if ($date <= $end_date) {
                $noEvents = 'No events are scheduled yet.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="eventBlock">';
                echo '<span class="hGc">'. $display_date .'</span>';
                echo '<a href="#" class="hLink">'. $event_name .'</a>';
                echo '<p class="dG margBot40">'. $event_description .'</p>';
                echo '</div>';

            }
        }
        if (isset($noEvents)) {
            echo $noEvents;
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Update - No events Code

```
if ($event_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_events)) {
        $event_stmt->execute();
        $event_rows = $event_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $noEvents = NULL;
        foreach ($event_rows as $event_row) {
            $event_name = $event_row['event_name'];
            $display_date = $event_row['display_date'];
            $event_description = $event_row['description'];
            //$end_date = $event_row['end_date'];
            $end_date = new DateTime($event_row['end_date']);
            $date = new DateTime('now');
            //$active_events = count($event_name);
            //var_dump($active_events);
            //if ($active_events === 0) {
            if ($date <= $end_date) {
                $noEvents = 'No events are scheduled yet.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="eventBlock">';
                echo '<span class="hGc">'. $display_date .'</span>';
                echo '<a href="#" class="hLink">'. $event_name .'</a>';
                echo '<p class="dG margBot40">'. $event_description .'</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        if ($noEvents) {
            echo $noEvents;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the relevant code here

```
$end_date = $event_row['end_date'];
$date = new DateTime("now");
if ($date <= $end_date) { }
```

The problem is you're comparing a string to a `DateTime` object. What you should do is make `$end_date` a `DateTime` as well, and your tests should work as written

```
$end_date = new DateTime($event_row['end_date']);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Do you know why my if isset would be outputting the variable when the condition is outputting the else?

Comment: @Paul It's not obvious why, but I've found `isset` as a test to be clunky anyways. I would set `$noEvents = NULL;` before the loop and then try `if($noEvents)`

Comment: I tried the suggest you gave for the $noEvents variable, but it still shows. I am taking this outside of the loop so that the variable doesn't output multiple times.